Cannot read property 'isReady' of undefined, js engine: hermes
I am trying to make an app in react native using supabase. The code was working completely fine before but now it is showing "Cannot read property 'isReady' of undefined, js engine: hermes" error. The full code for the screen where the error is displayed is :
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  ActivityIndicator,
  Pressable,
} from "react-native";
const segments = useSegments();
import { Link, Stack, useLocalSearchParams, useSegments } from "expo-router";
import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { useBlog } from "@/api/blogs";
import Loader from "@/components/Loader";
import { FontAwesome } from "@expo/vector-icons";

const BlogDetailsScreen = () => {
  const { id } = useLocalSearchParams();
  const {
    data: blog,
    error,
    isLoading,
  } = useBlog(parseInt(typeof id === "string" ? id : id?.[0]!));

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Loader />;
  }
  if (error) {
    return <Text>ERROR</Text>;
  }

  if (!blog) return <Text>Not found</Text>;
  const date = new Date(blog.created_at);
  const formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString();
  const formattedTime = date.toDateString();
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white" }} edges={["top"]}>
      <Stack.Screen
        options={{
          headerRight: () => (
            <Link href={`/(admin)/blogs/create?id=${id}`} asChild>
              <Pressable>
                {({ pressed }) => (
                  <FontAwesome
                    name="pencil"
                    size={25}
                    style={{ marginRight: 15, opacity: pressed ? 0.5 : 1 }}
                  />
                )}
              </Pressable>
            </Link>
          ),
        }}
      />
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
          <Image source={{ uri: blog.image }} style={styles.image} />
          <Text style={styles.title}>{blog.title}</Text>
          <Link href={`${segments[0]}/blogs/category`}>
            <Text>{blog.category}</Text>
          </Link>
          <Text style={styles.slug}>{blog.slug}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.author}>By {blog.author}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.createdTime}>
            Published on {formattedDate} {formattedTime}
          </Text>
          <Text style={styles.content}>{blog.content}</Text>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default BlogDetailsScreen;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 16,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    borderRadius: 20,
  },
  contentContainer: {
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  category: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
    borderColor: "black",
    borderRadius: 20,
    fontFamily: "Gabarito",
    margin: 10,
  },

  title: {
    fontSize: 24,
    marginBottom: 8,
    fontFamily: "Gabarito",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  slug: {
    fontSize: 16,
    color: "#666",
    marginBottom: 8,
    fontFamily: "Gabarito",
  },
  author: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: "#333",
    marginBottom: 8,
    fontFamily: "Gabarito",
  },
  createdTime: {
    fontSize: 12,
    color: "#999",
    marginBottom: 16,
    fontFamily: "Gabarito",
  },
  content: {
    fontSize: 16,
    lineHeight: 24,
    fontFamily: "Gabarito",
  },
  image: {
    width: "100%",
    aspectRatio: 1,
    borderRadius: 8,
    marginBottom: 30,
  },
  error: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: "red",
  },
});


The code was working fine before i added the Stack.Screen. So i tried to comment it and see if it works. But even after commenting the error persists.

i think cannot use stack screen here

Stack.Screen have to use inside Stack.Navigator

@Zuet can you provide a more detailed answer?

sorry. in expo is different with cli
